# Query not yielding the result in variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am working on retrieving data from MongoDB.

```
var newFolderObj = { "created_by": String(email), "file_name": String(folderNameToSearch)}
            Logger.printLog("")
            dbs.collection("uploads").findOne(newFolderObj, function (err, result) {
                console.log(result);
                console.log('Result from mongo');

                if (result == null) {

                    console.log('No user found');
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.send({ msg: "No user found", success: false, statusCode: 404 });
                    return;
                }

            });
```

When I give direct value for email and file_name({ "created_by": "Randrm@email.com", "file_name": "randomFile"}), then MongoDB will give the expected result. If I replace the same with var for dynamic retrieval, I am getting null result. Don't know what to do about it. Can anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: How do you "replace the same with var"? What's the code that does that?

Comment: @kevinadi Sorry for late response. As I am working on server side, the client request may vary. So, I am using var for storing the request and pass it to Mongodb as I have showed in code of the question I asked. Though, it prints the string value, even if it typecast to String, it is not yielding the result. If I directly place the string "likethis" instead of var, it will fetch the result. That is why I am confused

Comment: To test only I placed hardcoded string in query.

Comment: I tried a shorter variation of your code (using `String()` and a crafted object), and it works as expected, so that's not the issue. How are you passing the `email` and `folderNameToSearch` variables? Can you try printing those two to console and see if they contain the expected values?